# Dehumidifier (Whirlpool SS226) doesn't even turn on now

Tags: repair, appliances, dehumidifier

Hope someone can help me so I know whether to bother trying to fix it. I have a Whirlpool SS226 dehumidifier. I used it quite often last year. I just dug it out last week to use again. When I turned it on, it would turn on for around 10seconds and then switch itself off with blinking lights. I turned it off at the mains and tried again several times. Same reaction. I let it rest for a week and just tried it again. After plugging it in, there is no reaction whatsoever, not even a light. I changed the fuse (just in case) and still no reaction.

Does this sound like an easy fix or difficult and expensive fix (like the motherboard or something) please? I don't mind trying to fix it myself if it's relatively easy and inexpensive. If not, I'll know to get rid of it.

Please kindly let me know what you think :)

Comment: Not enough information to go on.  It sounds like the house power is not going though all the way to make it work.  Might be as simple and cheap as a broken wire or a connection fell off, or a replace/rebuild of expensive parts.  The only way to know is taking it apart and testing.

Comment: Thanks! Are there some tips you can give me on what tests I can do please?

Comment: If you are lucky, it is just the cord that has a wire broken in it.  Will need to check both ends still have continuity, a simple ohm setting on a multi meter should tell, move the cord around(bend it).  This test is done with it unplugged and able to touch  both ends.  If cord is good, will need to go further inside the unit.

Comment: If it turns on for 10 seconds, then the problem isn't the power cord.  Shutting down with blinking lights sounds like an error condition to me, and if I had to guess, the blinking lights mean compressor didn't (or couldn't) start properly.

Comment: If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that opinion based questions are off-topic. You're asking us if it's an easy fix. What might be easy for some could be very difficult for others, so we have no way of knowing if it'll be easy for you. Have you tried looking up the documentation for the dehumidifier? There should be a troubleshooting section in there. Follow that, then _you_ decide if it's "easy".

Comment: Have you emptied the water collection tank? Some shut down when full or dirty, was the unit stored in the same position as when in use? Not laid on its side.

Comment: It's just that last time I asked a question here about fixing my sink drain, everyone was v helpful in helping me find solutions and gave me step-by-step guides on what to do. I was completely clueless but I managed to fix the whole thing by myself!
I'm also clueless re dehumidifiers so would need a lot of advice. The problem with the troubleshooting I've managed to find, involves me pressing buttons, but nothing turns on at all; like I haven't even plugged it in. Yes, the tank is empty and was stored upright. I was just hoping someone could tell me if they think it's a lost cause or not :(

Comment: We could help with the drain because you included pictures of the exact problem and we recognized the problem as a broken part and had you get a new part.  So take it apart and check the voltage where the power cord connects to the circuit board. If no voltage, then you have a bad cord or bad outlet. If you have voltage trace circuit to see if something burned open.

Comment: Ah OK. I don't think it's possible for me to try and test it by myself then. I don't even have anything to check the voltage :'(

Comment: A sink drain and a refrigeration device are worlds apart in complexity and DIY-friendliness. There's not much you can do with them. I've resorted to buying the longest warranty offered because they seem to last a season or two and conk out. Sure enough, I had to use the warranty on my current one after a year. I don't buy warranties on anything else. These things are just that poorly made.

Comment: Hehe I realise that now. Think I got cocky after the sink drain and felt I could do anything!! 
Thanks. I'll give up on the dehumidifier and stick to the DIY-friendly stuff then :D

Comment: I saw part of an answer via email regarding something to do with changing TNY280, but I can't see the full answer on here. Not sure if I did something wrong :s